# Al seleccionar una option de un select ya no aparezca el append de una option anteriormente seleccionada

Tags: javascript, html

Hola tengo un `<select>` en el cual cada `<option>` genera un texto.
Lo que quiero realizar es que al seleccionar otra opción ya no salga la anterior, que solo salga una.

Por ejemplo:
Si selecciono la opción 1 aparecerá "UNO", luego si selecciono la opción 3 aparecerá el "UNO" generado anteriormente y "TRES", entonces cuando pase esto quiero que el "UNO" ya no aparezca.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $mensajeUno = $(
    '<h1>UNO</h1>'
  );
  var $mensajeDos = $(
    '<h1>DOS</h1>'
  );
  var $mensajeTres = $(
    '<h1>TRES</h1>'
  );
  var $mensajeCuatro = $(
    '<h1>CUATRO</h1>'
  );

  $("#select_num").on("change", function() {
    var seleccion = $(this).val();
    switch (seleccion) {
      case '1':
        $('#mensajeUno').append($mensajeUno);
        break;
      case '2':
        $('#mensajeDos').append($mensajeDos);
        break;
      case '3':
        $('#mensajeTres').append($mensajeTres);
        break;
      case '4':
        $('#mensajeCuatro').append($mensajeCuatro);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_num">
  <option value=''>Seleccione...</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
<div id="mensajeUno"></div>
<div id="mensajeDos"></div>
<div id="mensajeTres"></div>
<div id="mensajeCuatro"></div>
```

Comment: Es necesario que cada elemento tenga su propio `ID`? `(div id="mensajeUno")` porque se puede hacer de una forma dinamica

Comment: @JuanRivera Hola, ya lo resolví y de manera más dinámica y comprensible, cuando tenga tiempo detallo la respuesta

Comment: La opción más fácil es deshabilitar directamente la opción: `$("#select_num option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambié `$(document).ready(function() {}` por `$(document).on('change', '#select_num', function() {}` debido a que éste ultimo es mucho mejor para añadir eventos porque puede "monitorear" la selecciones realizadas sin importar cuando éstas se realicen.

También no tenia sentido tener muchos `<div>` si tan solo se muestra uno, por esto quedó con un div global `<div id="mensaje"></div>`.

Para el tema de que no se repita el mensaje, utilicé antes de cada caso `$('#mensaje').html('');` lo que hace que cada vez que se vuelva a realizar la función, el mensaje quede vacío.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#select_num', function() {

  var $mensajeUno = $(
    '<h1>UNO</h1>'
  );
  var $mensajeDos = $(
    '<h1>DOS</h1>'
  );
  var $mensajeTres = $(
    '<h1>TRES</h1>'
  );
  var $mensajeCuatro = $(
    '<h1>CUATRO</h1>'
  );
  
  var seleccion = $(this).val();
  $('#mensaje').html('');
  switch (seleccion) {
    case '1':
      $('#mensaje').append($mensajeUno);
      break;
    case '2':
      $('#mensaje').append($mensajeDos);
      break;
    case '3':
      $('#mensaje').append($mensajeTres);
      break;
    case '4':
      $('#mensaje').append($mensajeCuatro);
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_num">
  <option value=''>Seleccione...</option>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
<div id="mensaje"></div>
```